# Periodic background check for a very simple task (Android)

Tags: android

I'm currently making an app in Android that is checking an API which returns two things. Some text and a colour.

However I want this to be checked for updates every 15 minutes in the background and check every 5 seconds when the app is open. When running in the background it should give a notification if the status is changed.

Now I have checked numerous stackoverflow q&a's and forums, docs etc.. But I can't seem to find a good baseline for what I need. So many documentation that contradicts eachother.. I think that I need an Alarm Manager or a Service... but what do you guys suggest for my problem? The app may not harm the battery too much.

What I really would like to have is that the application doesn't have to "poll" the server every 15 minutes but that the application gets interrupted like.. "hey, there is a new status update". I can't imagine that messaging apps are constantly polling a server for updates? I haven't found much information about that topic... Any help is appreciated. Not asking for code but directions to get where I want to go.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to poll the server every X seconds/minutes, [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)([android guide](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html), [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html)) is exactly what you need. However, as you point out this is probably not the best way to go about things. While the app is open you may want to look in to passing messages between the device and server via an open Web Socket. Once your app is closed you could, instead of the app polling the server, have the server push a notification, via [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) or some such, to the app when an update is available.

Comment: Thanks! I really just found out about GCM. Seems a better alternative for the background issue. As the app isn't anything critical and I guess most users won't be happy if it drains 4-5% battery a day for checking information in the background they don't always need to know at a particular time. I'll dig into GCM right now!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing both the server side project and the mobile application, You can use Any messaging service rather than polling for the server, Because there has to be a pusher implementation from the server side to push the status to the MS.

For now `GMS` is free, I hope it will remain the same :). Otherwise, You can use `AlarmManager` and `IntentService` to achieve your goal.

Comment: Found out that you need to register every device to your GMS app and have to store them somewhere... Since thousands of devices will be added it's almost impossible for me to keep them stored.